# Get all brands which have some cars in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following models: **Brand** and **Car**

```
A Brand has_many Car
A Car belongs_to Brand
```

How would I get all the brands which at least have one car?

Answer (score 0):

All Brands that have at least one car:

```
Car.where('brand_id IS NOT NULL').joins(:brand).map(&:brand)
```

This is just grabbing all cars that have a brand, mapping over the cars and returning the Brands only. The joins part makes the query faster.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a join to Brand will add an SQL `INNER JOIN` to the query:

```
Brand.joins(:cars)
=> SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" INNER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."brand_id" = "brands"."id"
```

which will then only retrieve brands with cars.